# unable to import "numpy" or pandas using python3 or python commandline, but able to import the packages in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

In jupyter notebook server, importing `numpy` or `pandas` is okay.
[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Rxm.png)

However, by using `python3` or `python` in commandline, I am not able to import anything because of a package named SystemRandom. [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzOss.png)

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a file random.py on your Users folder ("/Users/chenyao/random.py") this file is interfering with the numpy import. You have two options:

- rename the file
- change directory

Answer (score 1):

It tries to import `SystemRandom` from `/Users/chenyao/random.py`. Remove or rename that file and it should work.